# MySQL 8 Error #14 EE_CANT_CHSIZE

Tags: mysql

I can't find any information regarding this error in MySQL.  Anyone know what MySQL is trying to do and maybe why this threw an error?

`code: 'EE_CANT_CHSIZE',
errno: 14,
sqlMessage: 'Can\'t change size of file (OS errno 28 - No space left on device)',
sqlState: 'HY000',
index: 0,`

Here are the errors in the mysql error log.

`Timestamp, Thread, Type, Details
2018-07-08 11:57:23.365761, 41607, ERROR] [MY-013132] [Server, The table '/data1/mysql8/tmp/#sql3435f_a287_2' is full!
2018-07-08 11:57:23.365764, 41605, ERROR] [MY-013132] [Server, The table '/data1/mysql8/tmp/#sql3435f_a285_1' is full!
2018-07-08 11:59:00.670292, 41627, ERROR] [MY-013132] [Server, The table '/data1/mysql8/tmp/#sql3435f_a29b_0' is full!
2018-07-08 11:59:00.670293, 41629, ERROR] [MY-013132] [Server, The table '/data1/mysql8/tmp/#sql3435f_a29d_0' is full!
2018-07-08 11:59:00.670291, 41608, ERROR] [MY-013132] [Server, The table '/data1/mysql8/tmp/#sql3435f_a288_1' is full!
2018-07-08 11:59:00.670294, 41619, ERROR] [MY-013132] [Server, The table '/data1/mysql8/tmp/#sql3435f_a293_0' is full!`

This seems like a configuration issue.  Does my tmp file size need to be bigger than any query results ran?

Comment: You need to add your sql so that others can analysis it

Comment: The question is obvious, but does it have enough space in the storage device?.

Comment: Yep, there is 1.3TB available on the data drive in which it's running and 128G available on the main drives.Is there a file size limit in the config I should be setting when queries execute?